# JsonResult interpreted as string by browser

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a controller action like this (very simplified):

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Submit()
{
    Response.StatusCode = Convert.ToInt32(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    return new JsonResult
    {
        ContentEncoding = Encoding.Default,
        ContentType = "application/json",
        Data = new {error = "xxxxxxxxxx"}
    };
}
```

The point is just that I want to return json, but the result in the browser is string.
Here is the property from the returned object:
[image]

To use this now, I have to do something like `JSON.Parse`, and I don't really want that. The controller action should just return json by itself.

I have previously seen a `responseJSON` property on the result object from the ajax request in JavaScript.

EDIT:
I'm using the jQuery form plugin, so technically it is that who makes the request.
Here is the code where I initialize the jQuery Form Plugin:

```
function initializeAjaxForm() {
    var feedback = document.getElementById('feedback');
    $('#upload-form').ajaxForm({
        url: '/xxxx/Submit',
        type: 'POST',
        beforeSubmit: handleBeforeSubmit,
        beforeSerialize: handlePreSerialize,
        success: function (data) {
            stopLoadingGif();
            feedback.innerHTML = 'Yay!';
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            debugger;
            console.log(data);
            stopLoadingGif();
            feedback.innerHTML = 'Nay!';
        }
    });
}
```

Here is the request in the browser:

[image]

EDIT 2:
Here is the response headers:

[image]

EDIT3:

This only seems to be a problem in the error handler.

Comment: The result in the browser is a javascript variable. It would really help if you show us how you call the controller from your client code.

Comment: what are you using in `Content-Type` and `Data-Type` in your jquery Call? Put your jquery call syntax in your question.

Comment: Please share your Javascript call

Comment: Added some more information.

Comment: You don't set anything for `dataType`, so it is supposed to be auto-detected based on the server response. What is the server response (including headers) you're getting?

Comment: I've added the response headers.

Answer (score 1):

return `JSON` object not `JSONResult` like this:

```
return Json(new { error = "xxxxxxxxxx"},JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Have a look at [**this article**](http://chsakell.com/2013/06/08/retrieve-json-data-from-mvc-controllers-in-asp-net-mvc/)

Comment: I can't get this to work either. I guess I just have to use `JSON.parse`, since I don't have all day.

Comment: doing this way you will json object you don't need to convert it to JSON